# Inline XML Bolding Not Working

Tags: android, xml

The following has no effect:

```
<string name="stringName">We are <b><i>so</i></b> glad to see you.</string>
```

Getting the string like this:

```
        sectionDetails = getResources().getString(resID);
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: try: sectionDetails = Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(resID));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getText%28int%29) instead of [`getString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int%29) as the latter will strip out styled text information.

> public CharSequence **getText** (int id)
>
> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID. The returned object will be a String if this is a plain string; it will be some other type of CharSequence if it is styled.

vs

> public String **getString** (int id)
>
> Return the string value associated with a particular resource ID. ***It will be stripped of any styled text information***.